# Not able to retrieve ConnectionString from app.config in .NET

Tags: .net, connection-string

This is a Windows Application. It talks to local SQL database, connection string is saved in app.config, i.e:
[image]

Code:

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CaseMgmtConn")`

is getting Nothing

I have the following setting:

[image]

[image]

What is wrong here? Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:**

I believe there must be something missing here, as I am not able to get anything:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CaseMgmtConn")
```

> Nothing

This returns Nothing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can access the Fields from the ConnectionStrings Fields in the Configuration File with the Help of ConfigurationManager. But instead of the code:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CaseMgmtConn");

Would recommend:-
string ConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FullValueGivenInName"].ConnectionString;

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the connection string from the app.config is by accessing/reading the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings (stirng array) property, then access the connection string by using the indexer in the array. 
ConfugurationManager.AppSettings is not the property to get the connection string.

Example:

```
var constring = ConnectionManager.ConnectionStrings["UseCaseMgmt.My.Settings.CaseMgmtConn"].ConnectionString;
```

For more information, visit the official docs at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings?view=netframework-4.7